# Passport Authentication System Not Working

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have an authentication system setup in my express node application, but I’ve been experiencing some errors with the passport authentication that I setup. For example, the registration system works fine, as does my validation system (which basically checks whether the user/pass combo is valid for my school’s grade book login). However, the actual passport login (which checks if the user/pass combo is a registered user in my mongoose database) is not functioning correctly.

> Relavent part of **app.js**

```
//passport setup
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
    user.checkLogin(password, function (error, userIsValid) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error:');
            return done(error);
        }
        if (userIsValid) {
            console.log('Valid:');
        }
    });
});
}));
```

> **user.js**

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

 var User = new Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   studentID: {type: Number}
 });

 User.methods.checkLogin = function (password, callback) {
     bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function (error, same) {
         if (error){
             callback(error);
         }
         callback(same);
     })
 };

   User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
   module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

> and finally, **index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

//register
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var studentID = req.body.studentID;

    areCredentialsValid(username, password, function (statusBoolean) {
        if (statusBoolean === true){
            User.register(new User({
                username: username,
                password: password,
                studentID: studentID
            }), password, function (){
                console.log('Registered:');
                res.redirect('./');
                res.end()
            })
        }else{
            console.log('Invalid Credentials:');
            res.redirect('./');
            res.end()
        }
    });
});

function areCredentialsValid(username, password, callback){
    if (typeof username !== 'undefined' && username !== null && username !== '' &&
    typeof password !== 'undefined' && password !== null && password !== ''){
        var cookie = {};
        var responseBoolean = false;
        var config = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/j_security_check',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'
        }
        };
        request(config, function (error, response, body) {
        cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
        console.log(cookie);
        var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/j_security_check',
            form: {
                'j_username': username,
                'j_password': password
            },
            headers: {
                'Cookie': cookie,
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'
            }
        };
        request(config, function (error, response2, body) {
            //console.log(response);
            console.log(response2.headers);
          if (response2.headers['location'] === '/genesis/parents?gohome=true'){
              responseBoolean = true;
          }else{
              responseBoolean = false;
          }
          callback(responseBoolean);
          return responseBoolean;
            })
        })
    }
}

//login
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

passport.authenticate('local', function (error, user, info){
    if (user === false) {
        // handle login error ...
        console.log('failure');
    } else {
        // handle successful login ...
        console.log('success');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

All help is appreciated. If its easier to deal with, the source code can be found 
[here](https://github.com/Scyon/genesis-api).

> UPDATE:
>   So with the latest suggestions, I get the following output:[image] And thus the login is functioning. However, the thing is, the login seems to be looping and recognizing the user once, then showing the "invalid login" message rather than just finishing the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 issues.

First:

In the app.js file, after you configure the *LocalStrategy*, you have to call *done* after you check the user credentials.

See:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
        user.checkLogin(password, function (error, userIsValid) {

            // You function should return the user data, not just if it is valid or not.
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error:');
                return done(error);
            }
            if (userIsValid) {
                console.log('Valid:');
                // call done here
                return done(null, {_id: 123 /* data to represent the user*/});
            } else {
                // call done here when the user is not valid
                console.log('Not Valid:');
                return done(null, null, 'Invalid credentials (or something like this.)');
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

Two:

In your login route configuration, you have treat the error calling the *next* function, and you error handler function will catch it.

```
//login
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('local', function (error, user, info){
        if (user === false) {
            // handle login error ...
            next(new Error('AuthenticationError'), req, res);
        } else {
            // handle successful login ...
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

**EDIT for the last comment:**

You have to check not just if the user isn't `false`, but also, it there is no error, look:

```
//login
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (error, user, info){

        // A error also means, an unsuccessful login attempt
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            console.log('Failed login:');
            // And do whatever you want here.
            return next(new Error('AuthenticationError'), req, res);
        }

        if (user === false) {
            // handle login error ...
            console.log('Failed login:');
            return next(new Error('AuthenticationError'), req, res);
        } else {
            // handle successful login ...
            console.log('Successful login:');
            res.redirect('./');
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

This worked for me here.

About the `(req, res, next)`, it is the arguments to the middleware.

So you call the /login route, you got the request and response, next, you call the `passport.authenticate`. This method, returns a `function(req, res, next)`, and finally, you pass the request and response for it.

See the code snipped from `passport.authenticate`:

```
module.exports = function authenticate(passport, name, options, callback) {
    ...
    // This is the function you call, when you do: (req, res, next)
    return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    ...
```

Check [this](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) out for more examples about middlewares.

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: i am simply getting no output

Comment: I've changed my answer, check it out! I believe it is correct now.

Comment: this seems to be almost what I needed. Just have a minor problem (which I updated in my question)

Comment: The original issue was solved right? Hmm... But Ok. Did you push the code to the github??

Comment: well the original issue seems to be solved, just needs some fine tuning in order to function properly (and then you will receive the bounty)

Comment: Could you push your new code to github, so I can see what exactly you have changed?. But before that. I see in the _user.checkLogin_ method its aways passing a _boolean_ to the callback. But, it shoud pass a _error_ (callback(error)) or a non-error (null) and a _boolean_ (callback(null, true)). In this case, credentials where correct. I don't know if it is the cause, but you can try it, and then, push you code, so I can check it out.

Comment: I found it. In the _user.checkLogin_ method, the callback has been called twice. How it is now: `if (error){callback(error); } callback(same);` change it to: `if(error){return callback(error); } return callback(same);`. Put the _return_ or  or a _else_ clause.

Comment: this fixed it. However, I am still getting `Error:` and `Successful login:` in my output meaning its still attempting to login twice

Comment: and also just wondering, what does the `(req, res, next);` line do? i do not really understand the syntax of that statement

Comment: It isn't attempting to login twice, you didn't check the _error_ argument. The answer has been updated. Check it out.

Comment: pushed my latest code to github. For some reason, the login isn't working and the `this.password` is showing up as null. Am I not getting the password from the database correctly?

Comment: Could you open another thread? I believe its fair give me the bounty. And then, I will help you with this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when validation is done you are missing a `verify callback`. Please try the below code:

In the below code when you create a LocalStrategy you have three parameter in the function namely username, password and done. Now when your `if (userIsValid)` is valid you need to invoke verify callback which is `done(null, user)`. So, that you can get the `user` when authenticated using `passport.authenticate`.

```
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
            user.checkLogin(password, function (error, userIsValid) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error:');
                    return done(error);
                }
                if (userIsValid) {
                    console.log('Valid:');
                    //Below is the code you are missing
                    return done(null, user)
                }
            });
        });
    }));
```

And the parameter in `passport.authenticate` are those which are passed from above verify callback. So, you will need to have only two parameters in callback in this case as below:

```
passport.authenticate('local', function (error, user){
    //your-code
});
```

Comment: what do you mean two callback?

Comment: i'm sorry I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @Steve Have you tried the code I have said you are missing??Please do try that.